# Tools to convert Windows Mobile 6 app to BlackBerry

Tags: .net, blackberry, windows-mobile

Are there any utilities which can convert my Windows Mobile 6 application to work with BlackBerry devices?

I have developed an SMS system for a shopping mall and I need to run that application on BlackBerry devices.  It is very hard to re-develop from scratch.

Answer (score 2):

Highly unlikely. They're completely different platforms. Unless you designed your application with this portability in mind from the beginning, I would think that a rewrite is your only option.

Is your windows mobile app written in the .NET compact framework?

Answer (score 2):

I am not aware of any such tools.
To do this you'd need a tool written specifically for this task. I doubt there has ever been enought demand for anyone to create this.

What you've found is the problem of porting language (probably) AND the APIs the code calls.

Approaches to trying to port it yourself will depend on:

- The language you wrote the WinMo6 app in (C++ or managed)
- The language you want to write the BlackBery app in
- Wha you're using to  store data on the app
- How you structured the original app (If you've separated UI, app logic & device specific functionality - it should be much easier.)

Answer (score 1):

Please don't try this approach.  Many apps for BlackBerry are already written as "quick ports" of other apps - meaning that the bare minimum is done. This often results in apps that offer horrible user experiences -- a problem that is often blamed on the BB UI, but in reality is far more often attributable to developers agreeing to "also provide a BB client" and making it a last-minute/minimal effort approach.

And to answer your question directly - I am aware of no such conversion app.